# Understanding package loading

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp

(solved, see the comments)

Recently I've been working on an API that has to interface with an already existing service. Everything seems to be working quite well, and my project is just starting to get large enough that I would see some benefit from throwing things into a package. As this is my first "real" project in CL, I think I'm not fully understanding the packaging/loading mechanisms going on here.

My basic problem is that I have a bunch of code that uses macros to generate functions/classes, interns them into my package, and then exports certain functions/accessors that people will eventually use to interact with the API. If I load the files individually like so:

```
(load "~/src/lisp/cl-bitcoin/bitcoin.lisp")
(load "~/src/lisp/cl-bitcoin/classes.lisp")
(load "~/src/lisp/cl-bitcoin/functions.lisp")
```

Everything works well. The functions declared by my macros are interned and exported correctly and I'm able to call them to interact with the API. However, if I attempt to do the following:

```
(ql:quickload :btc)
```

Quicklisp tells me that everything was loaded properly - and it seems that most of the loading process happened as I expected since all of my dependencies are loaded and available for use. The problem is that everything related to my package is not available. This includes functions that are exported directly from my package.lisp file. For reference, here are my .asd and package files:

package.lisp

```
(defpackage #:btc
(:use #:cl)
(:export #:set-connection-parameters
     #:reset-rpc-id
     #:with-connection-parameters
     #:btc-base-err
     #:btc-base-id))
```

btc.asd

```
(asdf:defsystem #:btc
:serial t
:depends-on (#:drakma
             #:flexi-streams
             #:cl-json)
:components ((:file "package")
             (:file "bitcoin")
         (:file "classes")
         (:file "functions")))
```

I feel like I'm missing something fairly obvious here - I've been looking into `eval-when` and other related loading functions but haven't been able to figure this out. Can someone explain to me what's going on here?

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Here's what my REPL looks like:

```
; SLIME 2011-02-04
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :btc)
To load "btc":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    btc
; Loading "btc"
..
(:BTC)
CL-USER> (btc:help "getinfo")
Invoking restart: Return to SLIME's top level.
; Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-ERROR #x30200175DF0D>.
CL-USER> ; Reader error: No external symbol named "HELP" in package #<Package "BTC"> .
; No value
CL-USER> (load "/Users/jordan/src/lisp/cl-bitcoin/bitcoin.lisp")
#P"/Users/jordan/src/lisp/cl-bitcoin/bitcoin.lisp"
CL-USER> (load "/Users/jordan/src/lisp/cl-bitcoin/classes.lisp")
#P"/Users/jordan/src/lisp/cl-bitcoin/classes.lisp"
CL-USER> (load "/Users/jordan/src/lisp/cl-bitcoin/functions.lisp")
#P"/Users/jordan/src/lisp/cl-bitcoin/functions.lisp"
CL-USER> (btc:help "getinfo")
#<BTC::BTC-SINGLE #x3020017DBDDD>
CL-USER>
```

And the code to generate functions:

```
;;;; package information

(in-package #:btc)

;;; externally visible functions - this class contains the public api for
;;; cl-bitcoin as well as the function building framework that we need to
;;; easily handle the multiple return types that are possible from the
;;; bitcoind server methods

;; function building framework - resolving function return types into 
;; specific btc objects (as defined in classes.lisp)

(defun create-btc-obj (fn result err id)
  (case fn
    ((:getbalance :help) (make-btc-single result err id))
    (otherwise (error "Unable to parse function ~S to a btc object" fn))))

(defmacro defbtcfun (name &rest args)
  (let ((g (gensym)) (result (gensym)) (err (gensym)) (id (gensym)))
    `(progn
       (defun ,name ,args
     (let ((,g (intern (string ',name) :keyword)))
       (multiple-value-bind (,result ,err ,id) (get-bitcoind-result ,g ,@args)
         (create-btc-obj ,g ,result ,err ,id))))
       (export ',name 'btc))))

;; function definitions (each of these functions should have a corresponding case in 
;; create-btc-obj above, otherwise a condition will be signaled

(defbtcfun help method)

(defbtcfun getbalance account minconf)
```

Comment: "The problem is that everything related to my package is not available. This includes functions that are exported directly from my package.lisp file."  Please give an example? What's not available?  Do you mean that some function definition hasn't been evaluated?  Or that a symbol isn't exported?  What unexpected behavior are you encountering?

Comment: In my `defpackage` I explicitly export 5 functions - none of those functions are available in my `btc` package after loading. Additionally, all of the symbols that would be exported by my macros (these are all exported and available in the `btc` package when I load the files individually) are not available after a `quickload`

Comment: It seems to me that the function definition isn't being evaluated considering that the export is explicit in the package declaration, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Could you _show_ us the error you're getting?

Comment: I've edited the post to include the REPL.

Comment: That's an image;  none of that will show up in a search engine.  Please copy and paste the text.  Anyhow, it says there's no external symbol named `help` in the package `btc`.  Looking at the `btc` package definition, I only see five exported symbols, and `help` isn't one of them.  After you load the files, `help` is exported from `btc`.  How is `help` defined, and where's the code that exports it from the package?

Comment: Thanks for posting the text!

Comment: No problem - I've also included the other code you requested. But no functions are available in the package after the quickload, including the ones that are explicitly specified.

Comment: what happens if you `(ql:quickload :btc)` the second time rather than loading the files manually?  Does `quickload`ing it twice get you the symbol export that you need?

Comment: Are you sure that the files that quicklisp is loading are the same as those that you're loading manually?  I know the default quicklisp directory for local projects is `~/quicklisp/local-projects/`...

Comment: I grabbed your code and put when I run SBCL from the command line and `(ql:quickload 'btc)`, the output that I see includes: `* (ql:quickload 'btc) \
To load "btc": \
  Load 1 ASDF system: \
    btc \
; Loading "btc" \
........ \
(BTC) \
* 'btc:help \
BTC:HELP`.  That row of dots is printed while the file is loading.  I don't see that in your output, and I wonder whether quicklisp is actually causing your _files_ to be loaded.  It's clearly loading the package definition, since the package is available, but maybe it's not loading the code, for some reason.

Comment: It turns out that this was just an incorrect configuration issue in asdf by me.. I accidentally set up the project in an incorrect directory. When loading the project, quickload was actually loading an entirely separate .asd file than the one that I was expecting. So, when I loaded the (correct) files manually, the code worked as expected - quickload was loading the wrong files. Thanks a lot for your help, it led me to figure out the cause!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it resolved.  You can post that as an answer and mark it as accepted.  That would help others who might run into the same situation (since searching through questions and answers is easier than searching through comments), and it will help keep the number of questions without accepted answers down.  Glad to hear you got it worked out;  happy Lisping!

Comment: I second @JoshuaTaylor - please post an answer to this question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

[Jordan Kaye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843440/jordan-kaye) posted this as [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293571/understanding-package-loading#comment30283285_20293571), but never turned it into an answer:

> It turns out that this was just an incorrect configuration issue in
>   asdf by me.. I accidentally set up the project in an incorrect
>   directory. When loading the project, quickload was actually loading an
>   entirely separate .asd file than the one that I was expecting. So,
>   when I loaded the (correct) files manually, the code worked as
>   expected - quickload was loading the wrong files. Thanks a lot for
>   your help, it led me to figure out the cause!